# 1999 Ford F250 XLT Super Duty won't go into 4-wheel drive low

Tags: ford, 4wd, f-250

So I have a 1999 Ford F250SD XLT 4×4 that won't go into 4-wheel drive low. It's a manual shift 4×4.

***What can cause this?***

When I put it in 4-wheel drive high, the 4×4 dash light comes on but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You should probably check the vacuum lines to the hubs there will be a solenoid somewhere in the engine bay that get's vacuum from a reservoir and then passes to the hubs.

Comment: I've had the same issue in s 4x4s.  Vacuum lime all three times.

Comment: It could be a problem with your transfer case. I just rebuilt one I'm my Jeep that was having similar issues. The shift forks were worn out. There was no grinding noise either like you'd expect.

Comment: Have you ever serviced your transfer case? Have you checked the fluids in it? Is there a lot of metal in the fluid?